# Google Cloud splash page and drain autoscaler groups

Tags: google-api, google-compute-engine, google-api-client

The issue is I cant find any documentation on changing a managed(Autoscaling) group into an un-managed instance group with 0 servers group. I've looked at pythons google.cloud and googleapiclient without any luck. They both show ways of managing each individually but not changing it. service.instanceGroupManagers().resize also no go.

Also https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/
also treats them individually.

I know they support this but I can't figure out how to do this without the gui.

[image]

Maybe someone has a better way of doing this. The idea is having a load balancer with a maintenance splash page in it with a RPS of 0 so it get no traffic. When we want the sites to go down for an update we drain all the active connection with the built drain feature when a server is being deleted. We do this by setting the instance group to autoscale no (Unmanaged) and 0 servers.

Comment: To be clear, without using the GUI, you want to change the instance group from managed to unmanaged, & turn off auto-scaling, & scale it to 0? Is this a correct?

Comment: Hey Dany, Yeah exactly.

Comment: You mentioned this is possible in the GUI, where have you found you’re able to change a group from managed to unmanaged in the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using a managed instance group, & all of the images are the same, the below options are available & much simpler.

It does not seem possible to change from a managed instance group to unmanaged in any way, so, I cannot provide steps to doing this through automation.

Best to use a rolling update or canary deployments. You can also use opportunistic or proactive update. These methods & how to use them (gcloud commands & API examples included) are [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-managed-instance-groups).

Rolling Update: Replace x instances at a time, i.e. imagine 3 instances, the first instance will go down & be updated, once it is finished the second will go down to be update, once finished lastly, the third will be updated. If there are 50 instances you can specify 10 at a time be updated, etc.

Canary Update: Imagine you want to test your new application. Only x/y (i.e. 1 of 3) instances will be updated. So some users will use the new application while some use the old. This allows you to test the new application in production without affecting all instances. If the new version is running smoothly you can roll forward the update (rolling update) or you can roll back the update by removing the few instance(s) running the new version.

Proactive update: Instances are simply recreated with the new version.

Opportunistic: If proactive updates are too disruptive, opportunistic updates will wait for the autoscaler or some other event that would restart or recreate the instance anyway to then also create the instance with the new template.

Hope this helps.